# Finding longest word in golang

Tags: string, go

Trying to find the longest word using Go from a sentence.

At the moment I am using this method:

```
func longestWord(s string) string {

    newArr := strings.Split(s, " ")

    l := len(newArr[0])
    long := newArr[0]
    var result string
    // fmt.Println(long)
    for _, lenString := range newArr {

        if len(lenString) > l {
            // ll := len(lenString)
            // l := len(lenString)
            d := &l
            p := &long
            c := &result
            *d = len(lenString)
            *p = lenString
            *c = lenString
            // fmt.Println(lenString)
        } else {
            c := &result
            *c = newArr[0]
        }

    }
    return result
}

func main() {
    args := "Monday Tuesday Friday Sunday Wednesday"
    fmt.Println(longestWord(args))
}
```

But I'm not sure that this is the best method to achieve that. Is there any other elegant way to do that? I know that there is one more method by using sort, but I would prefer more using the way with iteration between words.

Comment: Beware: ranging over a string will range over the number of bytes, which isn't always the same as the number of characters (`Hi` is 2 bytes long while `世界` is 6 bytes long). To range over the number of characters, use `i, c := range []rune(str)`. And, if you're targeting a terminal as the final output, consider [go-runewidth](https://github.com/mattn/go-runewidth) when measuring the width of monospaced characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### "Best" solution

We can even write it more compact than the other answers by taking advantage of the following:

- using tuple assignments
- initializing the `best` and its length with the zero values (`""` and `0`) and omitting the check for 0 words as the `for range` handles that properly
- no need to store `words` as a local variable as it is only used in the loop

We lose nothing from readability:

```
func longestWord(s string) string {
    best, length := "", 0
    for _, word := range strings.Split(s, " ") {
        if len(word) > length {
            best, length = word, len(word)
        }
    }
    return best
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Printf("%q\n", longestWord(""))
args := "Monday Tuesday Friday Sunday Wednesday"
fmt.Printf("%q\n", longestWord(args))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fPMo_9LXG1G)):

```
""
"Wednesday"
```

### Most compact solution

Note that storing the length of the `best` is optional and is purely for optimization purposes, since if we have `best`, its length is always `len(best)`.

Taking advantage of this, and that we can use named result parameters (and that all variables are initialized to the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of their types unless an initial value is provided–which for `string` is `""`), we can even write it more compact, again losing nothing from readability:

```
func longestWord(s string) (best string) {
    for _, word := range strings.Split(s, " ") {
        if len(word) > len(best) {
            best = word
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Testing and output is the same, try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GuFvtsoqZFV). Again, in most cases this is probably slightly slower compared to when we stored the length too.

Answer (score 4):

That totally works! You *could* make it a bit shorter, while also using longer variable names that explain a bit more about your intention.

```
func longestWord(s string) string {
    words := strings.Split(s, " ")
    if len(words) == 0 {
        return ""
    }
    best := words[0]
    best_length := 0
    for _, word := range words {
        if len(word) > best_length {
            best = word
            best_length = len(word)
        }
    }
    return best
}
```

You could change this to track a pointer instead of the word itself if you like.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
func longestWord(s string) string {

newArr := strings.Split(s, " ")

longestWord := ""
longestLength := 0

    // loop through the array
    for _, word := range newArr {
        // save length of word in the actual iteration
        length := len(word)

        // if length is larger, than longest
        if length > longestLength {
            // save the new longest word
            longestWord = word
            longestLength = length
        }
    }


// return the longest word
return longestWord
}
```

Implementation can be found on the [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pMAO4Tmezn9)

Comment: No need to check if array is not empty (`if len(newArr) > 0`) as in that case the range loop is just not entered. IOW it is safe to have range loop over empty array.